# Architecture issue: ActiveMQ and long queue

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic

We use AMQ for sending thousands messages from app1 to app2.
App2 sends all those messages to clients via http connections
But now we've got a problem if some clients consume their messages slowly all others clients wait because AMQ sends messages one by one so messages for slow clients block others for some long period.

Really appreciate any ideas how to resolve such issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate on how App2 sends out the messages via HTTP. Essentially, you need to design that part client independent, so that once you send a message to at least one client, you need to have the next message ready.

Maybe some internal queue datastructure in APP2 where each message is put into a unique queue per Client would do. Then each client can eat of each queue by its own speed.

Depending on you requirements and the total number of clients, you might even want to put one queue per client on the ActiveMQ server and have a Pub/Sub [pattern](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) putting the message into each client queue. This can probably be achieved if there is a limited number of clients.

Comment: thx Petter, we also thought about it but we have too many clients so it is difficult to configure queue per client also we cannot read messages from queue and keep them in memory because in case of some crash of App2 we loose too many messages. We are thinking about nosql solution.

Comment: Sure, if you really want persistency, a database is probably a decent idea, nosql or standard. Just to make sure, the publish/subscribe with multiple clients should not really be a configuration problem, the problem resides in keeping to many subscribing consumers, resource wise. The logic is trivial in either case